# Finding the Blob Centroid

Tags: algorithm, vb6, centroid

What is the algorithm for finding a blob's centroid (center of mass)?

[image: formula]

I found the above equation but I don't know how to translate it into VB 6.0. I looked online for a simple centroid algorithm in VB 6.0, but I did not find one that calculates the value of X and Y coordinates.

I tried to do the above algo in VB6.0. However, it always gives `1` as the center.:

```
Private Sub FindCentroid(bmp As PictureBox)

Dim area As Double
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim Xc, Yc, Xs, Ys As Integer

area = 0
For y = 0 To bmp.ScaleHeight - 1
    For x = 0 To bmp.ScaleWidth - 1
If bmp.Point(x, y) = vbWhite Then area = area + 1

Next x: Next y

Xs = 0
For y = 0 To bmp.ScaleHeight - 1
    For x = 0 To bmp.ScaleWidth - 1
        If bmp.Point(x, y) = vbWhite Then Xs = Xs + 1
 Next x
Next y

Ys = 0

For y = 0 To bmp.ScaleWidth - 1
    For x = 0 To bmp.ScaleHeight - 1

        If bmp.Point(y, x) = vbWhite Then Ys = Ys + 1

Next x
Next y

Xc = Xs / area
Yc = Xs / area

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the difficulty? This is rather straightforward, just finding the average (over blob pixels) of the x and y coordinates

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer I attached the VB6 code, the centroid is always 1. Can you fix the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your code you repeat yourself three times. First for area, second for Xs, and third for Ys. Secondly your code does not match the equation you provided.

Try something like this:

```
For y = 0 To bmp.ScaleHeight - 1
  For x = 0 To bmp.ScaleWidth - 1
    If bmp.Point(x, y) = vbWhite 
      Then 
        Xs = Xs + x
        Ys = Ys + y
        area = area + 1
    endIF
  Next x
Next y
```

I don't know VB syntax so you'll have to adjust that a bit.

UPDATE

To complete the algorithm normalize by area:

```
Ys = Ys / area
Xs = Xs / area
```

Comment: wckd, you forgot initialization of Xs,Ys,Area, and normalization of Xs,Ys by area

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer I assumed that user3819984 could take care of those simple details. They do not effect the algorithm so I did not include them in my answer.

Comment: Added the normalization because looking back that part is part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs in your code:

1. You wrote

   Xs = Xs + 1

instead of

```
Xs = Xs + X
```

2. the same for y

Other than that, the code is fine